# View Dirichlet character as a character of Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, characters

In Jaclyn Lang's article "On the image of the Galois representation associated to non-CM Hida family" section 2, the Dirichlet character $\chi$ module $N$ is also viewed as a character $\chi\colon\textrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^\ast$ without explicit explanation.

Is there any natural way to see this?

Comment: This should be on https://math.stackexchange.com A Dirichlet character modulo $ N$ is a (exactly) $N$ periodic completely multiplicative function $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{C}$, one for each character $\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z}^\times \to \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{\phi(N)})^* \subset \Bbb{C}^*$, then $$\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z}^\times = Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_N)/\Bbb{Q}) = Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})/Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_N))$$ and any character of $G/H$ is a character of $G$.

Comment: Your question is very standard. Learn a bit of class field theory and you will know the answer.

Comment: I would like to continue to object to the assumption that all mathematicians should be expected to learn the background that a grad student in our particular specialties have, and I think this question is just fine for MO.

Comment: For example, recently, class field theory has become relevant to people working in quantum information theory and sphere packing, due to a conjectural link between the Stark conjectures and SIC-POVM's https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05877 . I think people coming from the quantum world  and discrete geometry should be able to get an introduction to the key points they need from CFT here, not get sent away. (Not that I think this particular question comes from that precise background, just an excellent recent example of how all math is connected.)